# In the name of the lineup 4, 5 and 6, for example Bluecore-4, 5,6, is taken from the XAP4, 5,6?

Tags: microcontrollers, communication, bluetooth

Tell me please, in the name of the lineup 4, 5 and 6, for example Bluecore-4, Bluecore-5, Bluecore-6, is taken from the MCU XAP4, XAP5 and 6 respectively? Suspicious coincidence. Where can you read about this?The figure in the name is taken from the name of the microprocessor. I'm just not sure that it's XAP4 in Bluecor4.

Comment: Unless this is documented in the product datasheets, any answer is probably guesswork. Generally, no there is no rule that one product namespace needs to relate to the namespace of a different product. 'Clever marketeers' take advantage of this type of assumption some of the time.

Comment: @Sean I think your comment could as well be an answer (my 2 cts)

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is documented in the product datasheets, any answer is probably guesswork. As a first assumption, you might be right - but this is a prime example of why you need to refer to datasheets for a product (and also link them in your questions).

Generally, no there is no rule that one product namespace needs to relate to the namespace of a different product. 'Clever marketeers' take advantage of this type of assumption some of the time. This is especially the case when talking about a SoC built up from various IP elements from different companies.